# Displaying flow direction raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, flow

I have a raster with flow directions (geotiff). In ArcGIS I can use the vector field symbology option to display nifty arrows (see image). Is there a way to accomplish something similar in QGIS? I've looked at previous questions that suggest using the GRASS tool `r.to.vec`but it is already running for 5 minutes on a relatively small 4320x2610 raster. Trying the method using `r.to.vec` on a sample extent works but I am looking for a method that works with larger rasters.

[EDIT] The original r.to.vec would result in a  4320*2610=
11,275,200 point shapefile. For displaying purposes it would be better to leverage a pyramiding policy using some sort of plugin and on-the-fly analysis.

[image: Display Vectors in ArcMap]

[image: Display Vectors in QGIS]

Comment: I am not familiar with ArcGIS tool but the look of it is similar to `SAGA Gradient vectors from direction and length` or `SAGA Gradient vectors from surface`.